# 'ffmpeg' is not recognized as an internal or external command in Hapi js(Node js)

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, hapi.js

I want to add on watermark image to while uploading a video. I tried to use node ffmpeg but unluckily the git base command line says *"ffmpeg"** not recognized.

'ffmpeg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

```
const createVideoWatermark = async () =>{
    try {
        const ffmpeg = require("ffmpeg");
        var process = new ffmpeg('./uploads/video1.mp4');
        process.then(async function (video) {
            console.log('The video is ready to be processed');
            var watermarkPath = './uploads/watermark.jpg',
            newFilepath = './uploads/video-com-watermark.mp4',
            settings = {
                position        : "SE"      // Position: NE NC NW SE SC SW C CE CW
              , margin_nord     : null      // Margin nord
              , margin_sud      : null      // Margin sud
              , margin_east     : null      // Margin east
              , margin_west     : null      // Margin west
            };
            var callback = async function (error, files) {
            if(error){
                console.log('ERROR: ', error);
              }
              else{
                console.log('Waiting', files);
              }
            }
          //add watermark
            await video.fnAddWatermark(watermarkPath, newFilepath, settings, callback);
            return watermarkPath;    
        }, function (err) {
          console.log('Error: ' + err);
          return err;
      });
  } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.code);
      console.log(e.msg);
     return e.msg;
  }
```

}

Please help me to solve this. I am not sure where i did the mistake. Kindly correct me guys.

Comment: According to the [module's page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg), the lib "provides a set of functions and utilities to abstract commands-line usage of ffmpeg". So it doesn't wrap ffmpeg itself, it just calls it. This error sounds like you didn't [install ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) on your computer - or it's not in the environment's `PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have done using the child_process. I have added watermark using draw text.

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/video/watermark',
    handler: (request, h) => {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const str = "overlay=10:";
          const child =  execFile('/your-exe-file-path', ['-i', 'from-video-path' , '-vf' , 'drawtext="fontfile=./yourpath/font-filename.ttf:text="Added Watermark": fontcolor=white: fontsize=34:box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2', '-codec:a', 'copy', 'destination-video-path' ], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
              if (error) {
                  console.error('err:=====', error);
                   reject(err)
              }else{
                console.log('result: ===========', child);
               resolve({ message: child })
              }

          })
        }); //return end
    }
});
```